# Formula field check - if empty set the value to null

Tags: formula, formula-field

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that my workflow rule Date options that it currently returns `NOW()` but i need to check if the user have removed `field1__c and field2__c` then set that to be `null` otherwise `NOW()`

I am trying to check a formula value in a workflow rule that will evaluate two fields. A boolean field and a text field, if both are empty then set the value to ''

```
AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c), '')
```

error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()'. Expected
>   Boolean, received Text

Comment: Is it what you do for a workflow trigger or a formula field? These are 2 different animals. Please describe what you are trying to do, not just that ask for a formula.

Comment: workflow rules->field updates

Comment: Ok, so the field you want to set to Null should not be a formula returning NOW(), can you please provide more details on the logic for your case? It looks for me that what you are looking for is not a WF to update the field, you might just need to modify the formula field returning NOW() to be like this `IF(AND(NOT(field1__c), ISBLANK(field2__c), NULL, NOW())` and it should be a DateTime type

Comment: let me update my question

Comment: @NickKahn is this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to set the value of a formula field if the `AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c))` argument is true, if this is the case you might want to consider using an `IF( condition, value if true, value if false )` something like this may work:

```
IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)), '', NOW())
```

This may work however from your question it wasn't clear what the false condition was so i have left this with a generic string which you would need to change to be your desired false outcome.

**Edit** to show the correct NOW() outcome.

Comment: the false condition is `datetime` and i have the above formula like `IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)), '', NOW())` or `IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)), null, NOW())` but its not updating the field?

Answer (score 1):

Your third parameter is single quote `''` means it is consider as text

You just need to remove it

```
AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c))
```

### Updates

```
IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)), '', NOW())
```

Comment: I have added more info to make it little bit clear, after you post your answer I realized that its not clear enough.

Comment: @NickKahn check my updated ans..'

Comment: @NickKahn sure let me know if this worked or not.

Comment: the false condition is datetime and i have the above formula like IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)), '', NOW()) or IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)), null, NOW()) but its not updating the field?

Comment: @NickKahn is your `field1__c ` boolean false and `field2__c` is blank ?

Comment: yes both fields are false and blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37404/discussion-between-sfdcweb-and-nick-kahn).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like

```
IF(AND(field1__c = false, ISBLANK(field2__c)),  '' ,  -value if false-  )
```

Comment: yes i'm looking similar and i have updated my question